# Javascript window.find alternative for internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i want to implement the javascript function of [window.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.find)(). but it is not working in internet explorer. what could be an alternative for this code ?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve browser compatibility use

```
function windowFind(str){
    if("find" in window){
         return window.find(str);
    }else{
         return document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML.indexOf(str) > -1;
    }
}
```

This method is called *feature detection* and is used in many javascript libraries to achieve browser compatibility.

Comment: is this function will navigate to the position of the text ?

Comment: No it will not, it will return true if str occures in body, false otherwise. See window.find documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.find

Comment: oh okay, i was wondering if there is a function to that in ie. can you help me ?

Comment: You can scroll to element, but it is a bit quirky job, use a jquery plugin, here : http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/  But you have to modify your logic a bit more to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function contains(strs) {
    return document.body.innerText.indexOf(strs) > -1;
}
```

Comment: is this function will navigate to the position of the text ?

Comment: so you want to navigate to that text ?

Comment: you can make that string highlighted. i din't understand what kind of navigation?

Comment: it will point to the text that is found the browser. like in finding a text in a webpage using the search box of a browser

Comment: its just like in the  find text in a web browser.