# Implementation of 'window.find' in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari

I'm using the method `window.find` to search in a block of text, it's working in Chrome and Firefox but in safari and Internet Explorer 9, I can't use it.

The function that I'm using is: `window.find("some text")`
But it's displaying in the console the error: `window.find The method doesn't accepts the property or method find'

Now, I know that the method `window.find` is not supported by Internet Explorer.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Find-text-on-a-webpage-in-Internet-Explorer-9?v=t

How I can automatize the `Ctrl + F` in those browsers to search a text?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628649/javascript-window-find-alternative-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, the bugzilla document helps a lot. I going to search other alternative for all the browser, because in a future update they going to kill the window.search